# This works for any numbers smaller than 521153. This way it does not work and returns a very large negative number

Tags: c++, arrays, size, limit

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
  {int primes[521153];

  return 0;
 }
```

This works for any numbers smaller than 521153. This way it does not work and returns a very large negative number.

Comment: 521153 is a prime number. Do you really want to declare an array of half a million integers?

Comment: This appears to be a flags array for Eratosthenes Sieve.  Why use `int`?  Without any additional logic, you can at least use a `char` array.  But you should really use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exceeded you stack size. The C languages work like "portable assembler", where all language operations map directly onto machine operations, even if those operations cause "undefined behavior". In this case your stack collides with the heap, and your program overwrites its own brains and dies.

Use `int *primes = new int[BIG_NUMBER];` IIRC, that's well-defined to raise an exception if it cannot allocate that much memory. And your heap (where `new` gets its storage) can grow arbitrarily (on modern architectures), where your stack cannot. You C++ tutorial will define all these terms for you.

Comment: Since you are suggesting `new[]`, it might be helpful to quickly mention the corresponding `delete[]` call.

Comment: yup. And that's why "read your tutorial" questions suck on technical forums, because reproducing that tutorial, here, drags the forum down...